# Descobrir quantos são maiores de idade em aplicação Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, lógica

Estou tentando fazer um exercício em C# usando Windows Forms que quantas possuem mais de 18 anos.O algoritmo devera ler a idade de 10 pessoas. Porém quando eu executo o programa ele deixa eu apenas digitar uma idade.

```
public partial class idade : Form
    {
        int qtde, id,i;
        public idade()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 10)
            {
                i = i + 1;
                MessageBox.Show("Digite a idade");
                id = Convert.ToInt32(txtidade1.Text);

                if (id >= 18)
                {
                    qtde = qtde + 1;
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Existem" + qtde + "pessoas com mais de 18 anos");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da forma que você fez, precisaria talvez utilizar um InputBox, mas você pode fazer desta forma aqui:

```
public partial class idade : Form
{
   {
       int qtdTotal, qtde, id;
       public idade()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           qtdTotal = 0;
           qtde = 0;
       }

       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
          qtdTotal += 1;

          id = Convert.ToInt32(txtidade1.Text);
          if (id >= 18)
            qtde += 1;

          if(qtdTotal == 10)
          {
            MessageBox.Show("Existem" + qtde + "pessoas com mais de 18 anos");
            qtdTotal = 0;
          }
          else
          {
            MessageBox.Show("Digite a próxima idade");
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Aqui você digita a idade no textbox e depois clica no botão novamente até a contagem chegar a 10

Comment: puts...que burra eu, nem pensei dessa forma...poxa mto obrigada pela ajuda...realmente mto grata...desculpa mas to iniciando em programação.

Comment: Não é ser burra, você como está começando na programação ainda não possuí uma boa lógica apenas... Se a resposta te ajudou não esqueça de marca-la como Aceita, ou as demais respostas!

Comment: sim ajudou mto, marquei como aceita,mais uma vez obrigada.

Comment: outra pergunta se eu quiser mostrar 2 msgs mostrando a qtde de maiores e menores de 18 anos, terei que criar mais uma variavel para armazenar a qtde de menores...certo??

Comment: Isso mesmo e como está começando, adote um padrão para nomes de variáveis, pois assim você não se perde! Crie por exemplo, para inteiros, `int iQtdMaiores, iQtdMenores`, onde o "i" no começo do nome indica que a variável é do tipo inteiro

Answer (score 3):

Está tentando usar uma lógica de console em uma aplicação GUI. Teria que pedir 10 entradas de dados diferentes ou pelo menos fazer alguma adaptação nesta lógica.

Não posso fazer o melhor possível até por não ter acesso ao código todo, mas eu faria algo assim, se optar por ter apenas um campo de entrada de dados:

```
public partial class IdadeForm : Form {
   private int Entrados = 1, Maiores;
   public idade() {
       InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       if (!int.TryParse(txtidade1.Text, ou var idade)) {
           MessageBox.Show("A idade digitada não é válida");
           return;
       }
       if (idade > 17) Maiores++;
       lblMaiores.Text = $"O maiores de idade contados são {Maiores}";
       lblIdade.Text = $"Digite a idade {++Entrados}:";
       if (Entrados == 10) //lógica que não permite mais entrar dados ou reset
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/Processing.cs).

A contagem e controle deve ser feita fora do método, ela pertence ao objeto de formulário como um todo. Em console não precisa porque só pode existir um console então o dado vale geral mesmo.

Se não fizer uma conversão com verificação como eu fiz no código ele poderá quebrar. Não sei se é a melhor forma para apresentar o erro, mas para um exercício está bom.

Em um código real provavelmente o número da maioridade estaria em uma constante, para facilitar a manutenção.

Fiz suposição sobre ter esses dois *labels* que dei nomes melhores, mas nem gosto deles.

Se nada for feito para parar a digitação, como fechar o formulário ou desabilitar o tal do `txtidade1`, então seria bom a verificação se já chegou ao 10 como primeira linha deste método, nem deixando executar nada.